# ORACLE APEX - how to access APPLICATION_PROCESS_ID from inside the process?

Tags: oracle, plsql, process, oracle-apex

During the execution of an Apex process I am logging out into a table some data [local variables].

I would also like to log out the identification of the process itself- name would be best.
utl_call_stack.subprogram()() returns '__anonymous_block'.

In table `APEX_APPLICATION_PROCESSES` is the info about the process, but it needs `APPLICATION_PROCESS_ID` to identify.

I have tried to log out `:APPLICATION_PROCESS_ID` from within the process but it's null.

hence the question - *how to access identification of the Apex process during execution of said process*?